# how to open ubuntu if /etc/passwd file is lost?

Tags: dual-boot

I'm a beginner in ubuntu. In my root access /etc/passwd,i have given a command cat>Passwd, and my passwd file is lost.how can i access to my ubuntu now?

Answer (score 0):

recreate the file, your passwords are in /etc/shadow

take a look there for the user names

Strukture:

/etc/passwd
(USER)root:x(x=password is in shadow):0(UID):0(GID):root(comment):/root (PATH vor HOME):/bin/bash (SHELL)
example:
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash

Comment: other workaround: save your DATA and reinstall [and copy over your HOME]